# Find the last element in each loop regardless of element type

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I have a series of sections, with different types of elements like so:

```
<section>
    <div>Something</div>
    <a href="#">Some Copy</a>
    <div>Something</div>
    <a href="#">Some Copy</a>
</section>

<section>
    <a href="#">Some Copy</a>
    <div>Something</div>
    <a href="#">Some Copy</a> <a href="#">Some Copy</a>
    <div>Something</div>
</section>
```

I need to loop through each section and find the last element, regardless if it is a div or anchor.

```
$("section").each(function(){
      var last = //find the last element
      last.addClass('last');
});
```

I need help defining the variable `last`. Typically I would just use css' `last-child` or `last-of-type` to identify the last element in each section, but because there are different types of elements (anchors and divs) I believe I need to use javascript. 
Any idea how I can find this last element?

Comment: Strange but no one mention it: `$("section :last-child").addClass('last');`  http://jsfiddle.net/Q24XW/

Comment: See jsfiddle, it find last child for each section. And btw, if the purpose of class last is for styling, you should not use javascript/jquery at all, only CSS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$("section").each(function(){
      var last = $(this).children(':last');
      last.addClass('last');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/23EcJ/

Comment: LOL Or, you know, that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: Er, um, jQuery has a selector for that, as demonstrated in [Musa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18067646/157247). Leaving this here in case people not using jQuery (or who prefer to "go commando") may need it.

---

On modern browsers, you can use [`lastElementChild`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-ElementTraversal-20080303/#attribute-lastElementChild):

```
$("section").each(function(){
    var last = this.lastElementChild
    // Use `last` (possibly wrapped in a jQuery instance)
});
```

(You may want to wrap that in a jQuery instance.)

On older browsers, you can use [`lastChild`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-61AD09FB) and then work your way back via [`previousSibling`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-640FB3C8) to the last element (as opposed to a text node, comment node, etc.):

```
$("section").each(function(){
      var last = this.lastChild;
      while (last && last.nodeType !== 1) {
          last = last.previousSibling;
      }
      // Use `last` (possibly wrapped in a jQuery instance)
});
```

Comment: thanks for the extended answer

Answer (score 0):

I took almost the same approach as @Musa. You can see it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/nRtsF/

```
$("section").each(function(){ 
      $(this).children(':last').addClass('last');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:last` jQuery selector.

```
$('section').find(':last').each(function() {
    // Code here
});
```